# Update Salesforce record from .Net

Tags: c#, api, apex

I am trying to update a field(TestAccount__c) from the object Account in Salesforce, I have the entreprise wsdl already linked in .Net (C#), but due to my lack of experience I found this quite tricky, can anybody help me please: here is what I have so far:

sforce is the name of the sf wsdl

```
namespace UpdateSF
 {
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sforce.Account updatefield= new sforce.Account();



        if (updateField != null)
        {
            updateField.TestAccount__c = "Done";

        }
        else
        {

        }

     //this is not right
     sforce.SaveResult[] result = updateField.update(new sforce.sObject[] { updateField });

     }

    }

   }

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it should be something like that:

```
// setup binding (in init code)

sforce.SforceService binding = new sforce.SforceService();
sforce.LoginResult lr = binding.login("username", "password");
binding.Url = lr.serverUrl;
binding.SessionHeaderValue = new sforce.SessionHeader();
binding.SessionHeaderValue.sessionId = lr.sessionId;

// update account

sforce.Account updateAccount = new sforce.Account();
updateAccount.Id = "..."; // account id
updateAccount.TestAccount__c = "Done";
sforce.SaveResult[] result = binding.update(new sforce.sObject[] { updateAccount });

// todo: check result
```

Comment: Hello Alex, first of all thank you for helping me and your time. I tried your solution and I am getting this error and I run the page UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: Destination URL not reset. The URL returned from login must be set in the SforceService. Any ideas?

Comment: I've updated the answer adding missing `Url` initialisation. It probably should work now.

Comment: I added binding.Url = "https://login.salesforce.com"; before the binding.login and now I am getting this error: Client found response content type of 'text/html;charset=UTF-8', but expected 'text/xml'.

Comment: You are the man!!! thank you so much Alex. You made my day I truly appreciate it. One more question, where can I find more info about this topic?  thank you in advance!

Comment: In most cases just google it :) Also SalesForce has a pretty good developer documentation with samples (in c# as well) on theirs site.

Comment: I was trying to use Rest Oauth API to do this but I just couldn't make it work and someone told me ab this approach and it is way simpler. And How about if I only want to update accounts that have a checkbox true, where do I make the comparison?

Comment: I think it's better to let the server filter them (fetch with `select Id from Account where ...`) and then update each of results.

Comment: Alex, Would you please help me with my last question? I really need help. Thank you in advance!